# Is there a single word for "login/register"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm a programmer and often create login/register forms.  I'd really like a single word to use to describe a form that lets the user login/register.  Sort of like "authentication", but that's really more specific to the login part.  The next best I can come up with is "onboarding", but that really applies more to the register part.  Does such a word exist?

Edit: I'm really looking for this from a coding perspective, not to display on the page (i.e. it doesn't need to be user-friendly).  I just want it to be concise so that I can avoid variables like "login_register".

Comment: Why not steal from the hospitality industry and use *check-in*? Hotels have you do so whether or not you have an existing reservation on file.

Comment: There's a reason why you find **Login/Register** or **Sign in/Sign up** everywhere. So there's no ambiguity left, even more so for a layman who is perhaps visiting a website for the first time. Unless you want to create a page that _then_ leads to the _sign in/sign up_ thing, that's a different story.

Comment: I'm referring more to in-code than for displaying on the page.  login_register or loginRegister as variable names are annoying, and I'd like to be more concise.

Comment: "[***Upsert***](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2009/06/approaches-to-upsert.html) user" :)

Comment: Which is it? Login or register? Registration that takes you to login? Every website that allows self-registration separates login from signup. Abstract the concept to *greeting* or *intake* form. (although, generally, I'd expect two different form processors between login and registration, so two different forms?)

Comment: If it's just for coding, come up with an abbreviation like `logreg`, it doesn't have to be a real English word.

Comment: @bib That was just brilliant lol. I'm using that for my future sites since I combine them now. Thanks!

Comment: Entry is a loaded term, since it can refer to user's typing things in. We've always used logreg, and it's clear to coders without explanation.

Comment: Came here as I'm specifically looking what to name the code directory that will hold these, so +1 to @ggutenberg :). I'd shy away from `logreg`; good variable names are clear and descriptive, not confusing abbreviations (is it `login-registration` or `regular logging (debugging)` or `log regression (math)`?)

Comment: Variable names are off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because program variable naming is off-topic.

Comment: Very good question indeed! So many times I struggled with that. End up using words like "launch", "welcome", and "getStarted"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This form is the single point of entry for new and existing users, so I suggest

> entry

as an appropriate name for a single form for both login and registration.

The name makes it clear it's the entry point.

The only other name that springs to mind is *account*, but I think that would be better kept for something that allows you to change your email, password, settings etc.

Comment: I like entry the best of all the suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

what about signing? you sign in, you sign up, you sign out. Signing form.

Personally, I'd create separate forms for both functions, since they really aren't the same and don't call the same functions. This is why, generally, websites have a separate form for registering and logging in, even if it's basically the same 2 or 3 fields on the form.

Comment: If I sign up, I'm going to be doing something. If I sign in, I'm here.

Answer (score 5):

I would keep it general, trying to encompass the common ground shared by both "log in" and "register": they allow the user to interact with the program or website services.

I'd go with

> user admission / access

Answer (score 3):

A very good question indeed.

I would suggest **onboarding**.

Comment: Onboarding would include registering, but it doesn't seem to match logging in.

Comment: _Onboarding_ is rejected in the question itself.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet he didn't reject it, but he was skeptical about the word.

Comment: @jimm101 I beg to disagree. You are not "on board" until you're registered *or logged in*. Even if you're a registered user, if you're not logged in, you're not "on board" yet - you're probably still seeing the welcome screen. So I think onboarding can fit here.

Comment: I consider "onboarding" to refer to the sign-up/registration process.  Getting on board with the app/service/whatever.  I consider "I've been onboarded, but I'm not currently logged in" to be a valid statement.

Comment: @ggutenberg that might be true, but I still think we can say "I've not been onboarded, so I can't do anything on the app. I need to login or register."

Answer (score 0):

```
access
make session
authentication
auth
SSO
join & connect
```

Comment: This exceedingly brief answer does not meet the standard expected on EL&U. An answer here is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct* - preferably by quoting a reference (e.g. a dictionary definition) for each suggestion, hyperlinked to the source. You can [edit] your post to add this detail; for further guidance, see [answer]. Make sure you also take the **[Tour]** :-)